# How to encrypt a shared NTFS partition that is used by Windows and Linux on a dual boot system?

Tags: linux, windows-10, disk-encryption, dualboot

I use an NTFS partition for data that I want to access with applications both on Windows 10 and Ubuntu (Text files, Emails, Source code, ...).

Is there a way to encrypt this data partition such that it stays accessible for both OS that I have installed? Also it should be possible to make a backup, the backup however doesn't need to be encrypted (even preferably not encrypted).

Comment: It should be possible with Veracrypt. I don't know any other tool that can be installed in both systems.

Comment: [Windows/Linux dual boot full disk encryption - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366437/windows-linux-dual-boot-full-disk-encryption)